# My woodland explorer map doesn't have an icon on it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, my map doesn't have a house icon, to show where the woodland mansion is. What does this mean? I haven't been able to find anything online about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. If you re-create the world (in Creative) and go to the same villager, does it give you the same buggy map?

Comment: Are you using a texture/resource pack?

Answer (score 4):

Found a fix. This happened to me as well. All you need to do is place your map in a crafting table and surround all other 8 slots with regular paper. This increases the size of your map by increasing the scale (i.e: "1:2" now becomes "1:4", then "1:8", and so forth). Keep doing so until you see a house icon.

Answer (score -2):

Thats becuase the mansion was located along the edge of the map, so as the other answer mentioned, you can usually see it by expanding the map, but just to clarify, this is not really a bug.

Comment: What is the point of adding an answer here that basically repeats the other answer?

Comment: Because unlike the other answer I actually explain why it happened. This is not a bug as one would expect.